# How to disable ignite banner appearing on console?

Tags: logging, ignite, ascii-art

I have set up an apache ignite in client-server mode. When I start ignite on my server, an IGNITE banner appears in the console. This is the same when the client-side ignite initializes. Is there any way to disable this banner from appearing on the console.[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh7U5.png)

I have tried using `IGNITE_QUIET=true` and changing log levels in the configured logger file, but none of it seems to work.

Here is my ignite-server logger configuration

```xml
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%t][%c{1}]%notEmpty{[%markerSimpleName]} %m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="CONSOLE_ERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%t][%c{1}]%notEmpty{[%markerSimpleName]} %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Routing name="FILE">
            <Routes pattern="$${sys:nodeId}">
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sys:nodeId}" fileName="${sys:IGNITE_HOME}/work/log/ignite-${sys:nodeId}.log" filePattern="${sys:IGNITE_HOME}/work/log/ignite-${sys:nodeId}-%i-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%t][%c{1}]%notEmpty{[%markerSimpleName]} %m%n"/>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN"/>

    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log" level="ERROR"/>
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.component" level="ERROR"/>
    <Logger name="com.amazonaws" level="WARN"/>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE_ERR" level="ERROR"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE" level="DEBUG"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is how i configured the logger in my ignite config file

```xml
<property name="gridLogger">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="./config/ignite- 
    log4j2.xml"/>
</bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working correctly on the client-side ignite. The `IGNITE_NO_ASCII` and `IGNITE_QUIET` worked for me when I set it as System properties from my java code, before initializing ignite client.

```java
  System.setProperty("IGNITE_NO_ASCII","true);
  System.setProperty("IGNITE_QUIET","true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `IGNITE_NO_ASCII` system property or environment variable to `true` to prevent banner from being shown.

Comment: I tried setting this as an environment variable. But it's still showing the ASCII banner.

Comment: Maybe you're not exporting it to Java process? Try `export IGNITE_NO_ASCII` or just use `-DIGNITE_NO_ASCII=true` JVM argument.